# Where can I find a real to real FFT and iFFT implementation?

Tags: math, audio, image-processing, fft, complex-numbers

I have a complex to complex FFT, but I need a real to real FFT implementation...

This is because the noise cancellation algorithm I have works on real numbers in the frequency domain, not complex numbers.

Comment: Sounds fishy that it would take real numbers in the frequency domain.  Can you give a link or reference to it?

Comment: If you process data in the frequency domain and ignore or zero the imaginary component, the result of the IFFT may look nothing like the original data.

Comment: It's clear from the nature and large number of questions that you've asked on SO lately that you're trying to get to grips with noise cancellation but that you're missing a few conceptual building blocks that are needed for this. There's no way around this but doing some study on: complex numbers (basic math) and some general DSP topics (sampling theory, filters, FFT, etc). You might consider getting a MATLAB clone such as Octave so that you can play with DSP concepts as you study (and eventually noise cancellation algorithms)  without having to write (and debug) a bunch of C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only case where a real to real FFT would be applicable is if your time-domain signal is symmetric (`x(n) = x(N-n),  n=1...N-1`).  This is the only case that real input to an FFT results in real output.  Otherwise, real input still results in complex output from the FFT.

Real to real FFTs are significantly rare and are usually not implemented specially.  They are just performed with the real-to-complex FFT, discarding the imaginary output since it is zero anyway.

What is the noise cancellation algorithm that you are using that expects real frequency domain data?  Does it expect the magnitudes of the complex samples?  We need to know a little more about what the noise cancellation algorithm is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The FFTW3 library has a real 2 real implementation of FFT. `fftw_plan fftw_plan_r2r_1d()`
http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real_002dto_002dReal-Transforms.html

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Explain what the link says and how it relates to the question.